# npm Install Errors & npm WARN deprecated

Tags: node.js, gulp

The gulp from node.js 11.15.0 cannot be installed. I tried with 10.x version also, it's throwing same error.

```
$ npm install -g gulp-cli
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

changed 265 packages, and audited 266 packages in 57s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

can anyone help me to install gulp?

I tried remove the node_modules directory and then clear the cache by using
`"npm cache clear --force"` command. but no luck.

Also, having the issue when i run npm install

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\..........\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
....
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got it.
**npm install** working fine in my windows system.

Remove node_modules directory and package-lock.json then clear the cache by using this command

```
npm cache clear --force
```

and I removed the npm & npm-cache folder
**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm**
and
**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache**

then I tried to install npm

```
npm install
```

I hope this could help to someone.

Comment: But, still npm install -g gulp-cli throws warning messages

Comment: How about this
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue , Try to deploy your application on Netlify then you will see the build logs so you can fix your codes !